# julia c^3 results in wrong, negative number

Tags: math, integer, julia

So I was using light speed `c` to do some calculations in VScode and I found this:

```
julia> c = 3*10^8
300000000

julia> c^3
-1238598680542445568
```

It's obviously wrong.
But if I define c as float number:

```
julia> c = 3.0*10^8
3.0e8

julia> c^3
2.7e25
```

Then everything is fine.
What is happening?  Is this some inherent error within julia or I am asking some silly question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `BigInt`s for that as integers in Julia are normally 64 bits:

```
julia> c = big(3*10^8)
300000000

julia> typeof(c)
BigInt

julia> c^3
27000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the overflow behavior of int type

```
julia> x = typemax(Int64)
9223372036854775807

julia> x + 1
-9223372036854775808

julia> x + 1 == typemin(Int64)
true
```

While floating point numbers are not exact values, and they handle the mantissa and exponent separately hence they are able to return correct answers even for large order calulations.